# How can I use a javascript regex backreference in a function?

Tags: javascript, regex, backreference

`var string = input.replace(/\[noparse\]([^\]]+)?\[\/noparse\]/ig, '<noparse>'+removeBrackets('$1')+'</noparse>');`

This expression should be taking a string and encoding the parts wrapped in **[noparse]** tags so they don't render in a textarea.

I tested this as:

`var string = input.replace(/\[noparse\]([^\]]+)?\[\/noparse\]/ig, '<noparse>test</noparse>');`

and:

`var string = input.replace(/\[noparse\]([^\]]+)?\[\/noparse\]/ig, '<noparse>'+String('$1')+'</noparse>');`

and they work (without the desired effect).

```
function removeBrackets(input){
return input
.replace(/\[/g, '&#91;')
.replace(/\]/g, '&#92;');
}
```

What am I doing wrong in trying to pass the back reference into the removeBrackets function?

Comment: `[^\]]+` should be `[^\[]+`

Comment: You might want to bookmark MDN for future reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace` takes a function as callback and passes the capturing groups in the arguments:

```
var regex = /\[noparse\]([^\]]+)?\[\/noparse\]/ig;

string = string.replace(regex, function(_, match) {
  return '<tag>'+ removeBrackets(match) +'</tag>';
});
```

The first param `_` is the full string, unnecessary in most cases.

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work. Could you explain how and why that added function should work?

Comment: @user1755043: Check MDN for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: My problem was actually that I needed to use `([^\.]*)?`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression won't work, because of an error in the negative character set you're using. This fixes it:

```
input.replace(/\[noparse\]([^\[]+)?\[\/noparse\]/ig, '<noparse>test</noparse>');
                              ^
```

Then, to perform the actual replacement, you need to pass a function as the second argument to `.replace()` instead of a simple string.

Comment: I've been using the syntax as `([^\]]+)?` for many other expressions and it works just the same. Is it possible both are acceptable or is firefox catching my mistake?

Comment: @user1755043 No, yours was wrong. It should match until an opening bracket is encountered.

Comment: My problem was actually that I needed to use `([^\.]*)?`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1755043 That doesn't even being to make sense.

Comment: I spoke too soon. I actually used `([^]*)?`. I have a lot of reading up to do on how to put together regex statements.